# Finding the splitting field of $x^3-5$ over $Z_7$

Tags: galois-theory

My attempt;
 I substituted the values $0, 1, 2, 3, -1, -2, -3$ none of which yielded a zero, so I choosed (at random) $S_f=Z_{11}$ which gave only one zero

Comment: What is $S_f$? $ $

Comment: A splitting field over $\mathbb Z_7$ must, by definition, be a _field extension_ of $\mathbb Z_7$. Since $\mathbb Z_{11}$ is not an extension of $\mathbb Z_7$, your random guess is not only wrong, but _totally_ wrong. Your next step should be to _adjoin_ a cube root of $5$ to $\mathbb Z_7$ -- hopefully your textbook will have explained how to do that.

Comment: I'd still like to know how to solve this one - How do I even check for the existence of roots in fields that are not $\mathbb{Q}$ or $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: @SiddharthBhat: For finite fields you can simply check all elements. :-) Being smarter than that is possible but not simple; see [reciprocity laws](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocity_law).

Comment: In this case, you simply substitute $0..6$ and check? but none of them yield a root over $\mathbb{Z}_7$, do they? so how do you figure out "what extension" of $\mathbb{Z}_7$ works?

Comment: @SiddharthBhat: In general one can _construct_ the splitting field by adjoining roots, one by one if necessary. In this particular case, however, only a single adjunction is necessary, and the result is the unique (up to isomorphism) field with $7^3$ elements.

Comment: The splitting field of an irreducible polynomial $f$ over a finite field is always obtained by adjoining a root of the polynomial. It is a cyclic extension of order equal to the degree of $f$.

Answer (score 3):

The splitting field of $x^3-5$ over $\mathbb Z_7$ is $\mathbb Z_7/(X^3-5)$ because $\mathbb Z_7$ already contains $3$ cubic roots of $1$ and so adding a root of $x^3-5$ adds them all.

Indeed, if $u$ is the class of $X$, then
$$
(x-u)(x-2u)(x-4u)=x^3-7 u x^2+14 u^2 x-8 u^3=x^3-u^3=x^3-5
$$